# Duplicate Azure Initiative Definition Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions using PowerShell or az cli

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

Is there a way to do this with code? I see in the Azure portal there is a button in the UI that allows the user to do this, but I would like to do this in Azure PowerShell or using the az cli.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
#Get the initiative using the id
$initiative = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Id "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/xxx"

#Create the copy
New-AzPolicySetDefinition `
    -Name "Copied policy" `
    -DisplayName "Copied policy" `
    -Description $initiative.Properties.Description `
    -PolicyDefinition $([Regex]::Unescape($($initiative.Properties.PolicyDefinitions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100))) `
    -Metadata $($initiative.Properties.Metadata | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)  `
    -Parameter $($initiative.Properties.Parameters | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
```

This is a simplified example. Please read the [New-AzPolicySetDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicysetdefinition?view=azps-10.0.0) documentation entry to add more parameters.